# Transition css animation

Tags: html, css, animation

Please tell me how to make that the animation was not smooth but clear. At once the text disappeared and immediately appeared.

I don't need smooth animation!

EDIT: Right now the text goes out smoothly! I need the text to go out not smoothly, but sharply!

```css
div {
  font-size: 100px;
  animation: time_block 1s infinite;
  transition: 0ms;
}
@keyframes time_block {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div>TEST</div>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make it fade in and out?  "animation was not smooth but clear" is a very confusing statement

Comment: I don't need smooth animation!

Comment: Sorry, but "I don't need smooth animation!" is utterly unhelpful. You need to tell us what you DO want.  At this time your question is unanswerable

Answer (score 1):

You should start at opacity 0. Then you can use `animation-direction:alternate` to make the animation go from 0 to 1 and then back to 0.

```css
div {
  font-size: 100px;
  animation: time_block 1s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
  transition: 0ms;
}
@keyframes time_block {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
```

Comment: Didn't know about the `alternate` direction directive... certainly easier than my percentage version

Comment: I don't need smooth animation!

Answer (score -1):

You can increase the animation time to 2 or 3 secs and add the forwards value to animation-fill-mode so that it retains the values set by the final keyframe after the animation is completed.

Here is the code :

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div {
                font-size: 100px;
                animation: time_block 2s forwards;

            }
            @keyframes time_block {
                to {
                    opacity: 0;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TEST</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps you.